# I am trying to debug an ASP.NET MVC shared project where breakpoints are not getting hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I try to debug a shared project through devops services to me, the breakpoints are not getting hit. Step in and step over options are grayed out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try to close the `Visual studio` and `re open as administrator`, make sure you `debug mode` been selected in visual studio as well.